# How to accept .csv, .xsl, .xslx files using jQuery file upload?

Tags: jquery, file, upload, blueimp

I am trying to use it https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

I've implemented this with PHP to manage uploaded files, everything works, I want to limit file type, the uploader needs to accept are .CSV, .XSL, .XSLX

I don't know how to configure it since there no explanation about file types to accept these extensions.

Snippet for @c25

```
       $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (e, data) {
            // Add each uploaded file name to the #files list
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                $('<li/>').text(file.name).appendTo('#files');
            });
        },
        progressall: function (e, data) {
            // Update the progress bar while files are being uploaded
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $('#progress .bar').css(
                'width',
                progress + '%'
            );
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

I found the following on the [demo websites](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) source:

```
$.widget('blueimp.fileupload', $.blueimp.fileupload, {

    options: {

        // The regular expression for allowed file types, matches
        // against either file type or file name:
        acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
        // The maximum allowed file size in bytes:
        maxFileSize: 10000000, // 10 MB
        // The minimum allowed file size in bytes:
        minFileSize: undefined, // No minimal file size
        // The limit of files to be uploaded:
        maxNumberOfFiles: 10,
        */

        // Function returning the current number of files,
        // has to be overriden for maxNumberOfFiles validation:
        getNumberOfFiles: $.noop,

        // Error and info messages:
        messages: {
            maxNumberOfFiles: 'Maximum number of files exceeded',
            acceptFileTypes: 'File type not allowed',
            maxFileSize: 'File is too large',
            minFileSize: 'File is too small'
        }
    },
```

The documentation for the options can be found [here](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#processqueue).

**EDIT**

I found that you will need 2 more files with the basic plugin. The [jquery.fileupload-process.js](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/js/jquery.fileupload-process.js) 
and
[jquery.fileupload-validate.js](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/js/jquery.fileupload-validate.js). Then modify the validate.js file to accept only the file extensions you need. The documentation for all this can be found [here](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Plugin-files). **You should really read the documentation!**

Comment: I've tried it, It really didn't help me. It only outputs properties of uploaded file. Take a look this demo https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/ there a note below "Only image files (JPG, GIF, PNG) are allowed in this demo (by default there is no file type restriction)." I am not able to find this code.

Comment: The code I posted is how it is restricting the file types via this line: `acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,`

Comment: added a snippet in original post, I do not understand how to implement options.

Comment: @Ivan updated. Read the documentation, its all there!

Comment: I already read documentation, it's not good documentation, I was looking to implement like .fileupload({options: {accepFileTypes: ...}}) without editing the plugin, anyway I edited this plugin and it works. I mark your answer as accepted, but it's not good answer...

Comment: Wow that is useless documentation... How is editing the plugin an acceptable way to change the accepted file types? It looks like you should just have to change the regex but mine throws nonsensical unexpected character exceptions when I do.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the filetype in PHP with these lines of code:

```
function upload_file(){
  $types = array('text/csv', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');

  if(in_array($_FILES['uploaded_filename']['type'], $types)){
      //Manage the uploaded file here
  } else {
      //Handle the excluded filetypes here
}
```

Here, you can see the complete MIME Types List: http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html

Comment: I need JS for behavior purposes, I already implemented this, it could upload files, otherwise wont upload which is not csv and others, the problem is client side, it acts like accepting all files

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the file that is doing the [validation](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/js/jquery.fileupload-validate.js). Its actually extending the main plugin.